# Why onbind () method highly recommend to implement in even in started service

Tags: android, service

It is mentioned in Service's Google Doc to implement onBind() method always even if we are not going to bind Serive.

> You must always implement this method, but if you don't want to allow binding, then you should return null.

[For Service doc click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).
I am confused, what's the need to implement onbind() method when I am not going to bind service (I have to start service only)?
Why not to left this method at all if I only start service through startService() method.
Is there any problem I may encounter If I don't implement this method at all?

Comment: "Is there any problem I may encounter If I don't implement this method at all?" - Yeah, it won't compile. `onBind()` is an abstract method. You have to implement it in any concrete subclass of `Service`.

Comment: That is very obvious Mike but the point is why Google design this in such a way?

Comment: It clearly was not obvious if you thought you could subclass `Service` without implementing that method. Why else would you have asked that question? Anyway, you'd have to ask the designers. And, really, if CommonsWare doesn't know why, or can't think of a reason why, I doubt you'll get the answer here, unless one of the designers happens to stumble upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

For unknown reasons, Google made `Service` be an `abstract` class and made `onBind()` be an `abstract` method. As Mike M points out in a comment, if you do not implement `onBind()`, your `Service` subclass will fail to compile.

Some existing `Service` subclasses, like `IntentService`, implement `onBind()` for you, saving you the trouble.

Comment: But that is the question in fact, why Google design this in such a way?